# SVG symbols not being displayed in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg, icons, symbols

I'm currently using SVG symbols to display icons. This works in IE, Chrome, and Safari but the icons don't show up in Firefox. There are lots of similar questions on StackOverflow but most of them are older or aren't using symbols.

I'm loading all of the icons in `index.html` using the following markup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display:none">
    <symbol id="user" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <path d="...">
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

I then use the symbols like this within my views:

```
<svg ng-class="type" class="main-nav-icon">
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#user"></use>
</svg>
```

With the following css:

```
.main-nav-icon {
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

In Firefox, the svg markup ends up looking like this in the debugger:

```
<svg class="main-nav-icon" ng-class="type"><use xlink:href="#user"></use></svg>
```

But nothing is being displayed (although the spacing is correct meaning a 32px by 32px element is being displayed, it's just empty).  What do I need to do to make this work?

This is what the head of my html looks like:

```
<!doctype html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densityDpi=device-dpi">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/vendor-app.css">
    <base href="/">
  </head>
```

### Updated JsFiddle demonstrating the problem

http://jsfiddle.net/r7ger34b/2/

Open the link in Chrome and the icon is displayed.
Open the link in Firefox and no icon is displayed.

Comment: Create a jsfiddle or something that actually shows the issue. The display none is generally not a good idea but with a symbol you may get away with it.

Comment: `use` elements are self-closing so `<use xlink:href="#user"/>` is the correct usage.

Comment: What is your DOCTYPE?

Comment: I created a Jsfiddle but the problem is that it works fine there in Firefox, but displays nothing on my site. I do have a base tag in my html.  This breaks Firefox?

Comment: base prepends to the # so your links are not pointing where you think they are.

Comment: The base tag is required for AngularJS, and everything works in IE and Chrome so what do I need to do to get the links working in all three?

Comment: 5 options, pick one. a) remove the base tag. b) make the base tag always be the page URL. c) use absolute URLs for the `<use>` hrefs d) don't use Firefox. e) move the SVG to object or iframe external references.

Comment: How do options b and c work with a single page app? I'm using HTML location so my index page is loaded regardless of the requested page. If my URL is currently http://example.com/main what does the `<use>` link need to be? I've tried http://example.com/main/#todo, http://example.com/#todo, http://example.com/todo, http://example.com/main/todo, but the icon is never displayed.

Comment: For the jsfiddle it would be `http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/#day` (note that ids are not allowed to start with a digit). You need to target the frame for the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is:

```
<base href="/">
```

Remove that will work in the Firefox.

Comment: This is not a usable solution for something like angular html5 mode that requires the base tag to be in place. Here's an alternative that helps fix it: https://gist.github.com/leonderijke/c5cf7c5b2e424c0061d2

Answer (score 1):

on your jsfiddle, just remove on css part the block :

```
 </style>
    <base href="/">
    <style>
```

and your svg will show on firefox