# SilverStripe wysiwyg images not working without base_tag

Tags: silverstripe

I have removed the base_tag from my template [to allow for the use of SVG icon sprites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27306759/svg-symbols-not-being-displayed-in-firefox). A side effect of this is that images on pages other than the home page break.

The `HTMLEditorField::saveInto()` method is forcing a relative url on the image and they end up pointing to `/some-page-other-than-home/assets/image.jpg` which is wrong.

How do I get images to resolve to the root `/assets/` directory rather than pointing to `/some-page-other-than-home/assets/`.

Answer (score 1):

SilverStripe provides [extension hooks](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/developer_guides/extending/extensions/#modifying-existing-methods) on some methods. The HTMLEditorField has a ['processImage' hook](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-HtmlEditorField.html#146) that you can tap into.

You can hook into this method with the following:

**1. Create your extension configuration.**

*/mysite/_config/Config.yml*

```
HtmlEditorField:
  extensions:
    - HTMLEditorFieldExtension
```

**2. Create a the HTMLEditorFieldExtension class.**

*/mysite/code/HTMLEditorFieldExtension.php*

```
<?php
class HTMLEditorFieldExtension extends DataExtension
{
    // This method name must be the same as the extension hook
    public function processImage($image, $img) {

        // Get the image src attribute
        $src = $img->getAttribute('src');

        // Concatenate  a leading slash
        $img->setAttribute('src', '/' . $src);
    }
}
```

**3. Run a dev/build.**

This needs to be done so SilverStripe can find the new extension. After this your images should now have the missing leading slash.